# Can get timestamp of frame in video with pyav - python

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, timestamp, pts, pyav

How can I get timestamp of a frame in a video or rtmp stream from pts and time_base or duration? Thanks a lot!

```
import av
def init_input(file_name):
    global a
    container = av.open(file_name)
    a = container.duration
    return container.decode(video=0)
url = "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov"
stream1 = init_input(url)
for frame1 in stream1:
    print(frame1.pts)
    print(frame1.time_base)
```

PS: frame.time is incorrect with actual time

Answer (score 6):

As of writing, this bug was [just fixed](https://github.com/mikeboers/PyAV/commit/32d2f0ca45ebe6006b95cebdaf3de6bca3d85ed5) on GitHub.

If you need this to work with the currently released PyAV (i.e. on the PyPI), then you can use the `time_base` on the video `Stream`:

```
import av

url = "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov"

container = av.open(url, options={'rtsp_transport': 'tcp'})
stream = container.streams.video[0]

for frame in container.decode(stream):
    print(float(frame.pts * stream.time_base))
```

Comment: What's wrong with `frame.time`?